# Capture string between two words but only 1st time

Tags: python, regex

I have string like:

```
 text = "Why do Humans need to eat food? Humans eat food to survive."
```

I want to capture everything between `Human` and `food` but only 1st time.

**Expected Output**

```
Humans need to eat food
```

**My Regex:**

```
p =r'(\bHumans?\b.*?\bFoods?\b)'
```

**Python Code:**

```
re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
```

The code correctly captures the string between Human and Food but it doesn't stops at 1st capture.

**Research**:

I have read that to make it non-greedy I need to put `?` but I am unable to figure out where I should keep it to make it non-greedy. All other permutation and combination I tried I can't stopped it at 1st match.

**Update**

I am writing a lot of regexes to capture various other entities like this and parsing them in one shot and hence I can't change my `re.findall` logic.

Comment: Have you tried this `re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)[0]`?

Comment: Actually I am writing a lot of regexes and parsing them all in one shot and hence I can't change my `re.findall` logic

Comment: `re.findall` captures all of the matches in the provided `text`, it doesn't have to do anything with multiple regexes, it'll only use one regex at a time.

Comment: @xbound instead of using `re.findall` and then picking its first match, `re.search` would be a better option, as it won't search for all of the matches, and would stop after finding the first one, and obviously would be faster.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad: I am aware that `re.findall` works one regex at a time, but I need to compile several other regexes with same piece of code and hence can't implement @xbound solution or use `re.search`.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal as long as you need only one match for each of your regexes, I think you're good to change it to `re.search`

Comment: Sure will try!! Thanks for your inputs!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding the first match only, Toto's answer is best but as you said you need to use `findall` only, you can just append `.*` at the end of your regex to match remaining text which won't result in any matches further.

```
(\bHumans?\b.*?\bFoods?\b).*
                          ^^ This eats remaining part of your text due to which there won't be any further matches.
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6iU1d7/1)**

Sample Python codes,

```
import re

text = "Why do Humans need to eat food? Humans eat food to survive."
p =r'(\bHumans?\b.*?\bFoods?\b).*'
print(re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL))
```

Prints,

```
['Humans need to eat food']
```

Comment: One more help please, in the same example if I simply need to get `need to eat` by using `re.findall()`. Can it be done by modifying the regex only ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: You can use `\bneed to eat\b` regex to get all instances of that string but why would you do that? Can you tell what you are trying to achieve? Show some string and tell the expected output?

Comment: I want string between 2 words, just like my question above but don't want the starting and the end word. So, string like `text = "Why do Humans need to eat food? Humans eat food to survive."` but the answer instead of `Human needs to eat food` should be `needs to eat`

Comment: For getting a string between two words, say, between `Humans` and `food` and without those words getting included in your matched text, you will need to use positive look ahead and look behind. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/6iU1d7/2)

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5):

Use `search` instead of `findall`:

```
import re
text = "Why do Humans need to eat food? Humans eat food to survive."
p =r'(\bHumans?\b.*?\bFoods?\b)'
res = re.search(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
print(res.groups())
```

**Output:**

```
('Humans need to eat food',)
```

Or add `.*` at the end of the regex:

```
import re
text = "Why do Humans need to eat food? Humans eat food to survive."
p =r'(\bHumans?\b.*?\bFoods?\b).*'
#                      here ___^^
res = re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Actually I am writing a lot of regexes and parsing them all in one shot and hence I can't change my `re.findall` logic

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Why do Humans need to eat food? Humans eat food to survive."
>>> re.search(r'Humans.*?food', text).group() # you want the all powerful non-greedy '?' :)
'Humans need to eat food'
```